# Small ListViews with header/footer are empty after rotating screen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, screen-orientation, listview-adapter

I have a very strange issue with `ListView` on Android.

When I rotate the device, my `ListView`s with headers and/or footers become invisible if they are too small.

The items of the `ListView` are correct. They are restored from `savedInstanceState` correctly, and a new `Adapter` is created and bound in activity's `onCreate`. I even added logging to adapter's `getCount` and `getView`, and it showed correct result.

The problem is that the list is invisible only if it's shorter than its height (tried with `match_parent` and constant height):

- If there are no overflowing items at all (for example, 8 items), the list completely disappears when the screen is rotated.
- If there is overflow only in landscape mode with `match_parent` height (16 items), the list disappears when I go to portrait mode and reappears in landscape mode.
- If there is overflow in both orientations or with constant size (24 items), everything is displayed correctly.

The list is also displayed correctly before I rotate the device.

What's wrong with the list?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen. ;-)

Comment: @PaulBurke http://pastebin.com/K54Zs7L0 (app name hidden)

Comment: The same thing also happens to lists in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by replacing `addHeaderView`/`addFooterView` with creating the header/footer in the adapter (using `isEnabled`/`getView`/`getViewCount`). But still, I'd like to know how to overcome this while using true headers and footers.